# more options to use with onRegionLabelShow: function with jVectormap

Tags: jquery, json, jvectormap

I've searched everywhere for the answer to this, but since my knowledge of jQuery is still near non-existent, I am not sure if I am searching for the right question.  I hope someone here is able to give me some assistance.

I am creating a map using jvectormap and building it at http://www.roosteromg.com/sandbox/map2. I was successful in creating each rollover state a different color based on political party, but I need to be able to add a few lines of text to the Show label based on the state being rolled over.

For example:  If you rollover say, Pennsylvania, it currently displays the state name using the `onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){ label.html( ''+label.html()`, but I need to add two lines of plain text after the name of the state.

If working like I need it, the state, when rolled over would look like:

Pennsylvania
 
Sen. John Doe (R) - Voted Yes
Sen Jane Doe (D) - Voted No

Thank you in advance for your help.

Charles Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is a definition with the texts to show for each state under the form of `'stateCode': 'text'`.

```
var labels = {
    'US-AL': 'Sen. John Doe (R) - Voted Yes<br/>Sen Jane Doe (D) - Voted No',
    'US-AK': 'Some other text, you can make use of html tags'
};
```

To be able to display the custom text attached to a state, you need to slightly modify the `onRegionLabelShow` function.

```
onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
    if (!labels.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
        // no text found, return standard state name
        return true;
    }

    // construct label for state with extra text
    label.html(
        '<strong>' + label.html() + '</strong><br/>' + labels[code]
    );
}
```

Comment: You are a genius!!!  You cannot imagine how happy I am for this solution.  

Thanks you, I appreciate it.

Chuck

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if the solution worked for you.

Comment: I think it changed to `onRegionTipShow`